# Handling unknown properties with the Spring Data MongoDB driver

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I want to be able to load an object from a MongoDB collection and be able to handle unknown properties / elements in the document using the Spring Data MongoDB driver. Primarily when the object is saved again, that any unknown properties are not discarded.

I've seen the equivalent feature in the .net driver (using the [BsonExtraElements](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/#supporting-extra-elements) attribute), but cannot find any documentation or articles that discuss this for Spring MongoDB.

I wondered if I've missed something, or do I need to consider implementing or extending my own MappingMongoConverter to handle this?

Thanks,

Adam

Answer (score 1):

The way to go is using the `update(…)` method instead of `save(…)` in `MongoTemplate` as this does not replace the document with the data of the object to be saved but triggers and update to the document instead, selectively setting individual fields.

Comment: If I use the update() method, is there a way of mapping my POJO to a new update() object? So that I can have a generic update() method that can handle extra fields?